# R: How to convert this integer format to date

Tags: r, datetime

Data retrieved from a system API gives me this type of integer for the field `run_started` such as `1618269381119`, `1618304423122`... Does somebody know how to convert that to datetimes in R? I have not seen this format before and `lubridate::as_datetime` gives me a date in year 53282, where it should be very recent, 2020 or 2121.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like the current time millies... milliseconds since 1.1.1970

Comment: Try: `as.POSIXct(c(1618269381119, 1618304423122)/1000, origin = "1970-1-1", tz="GMT")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert from milliseconds to seconds and then to date:

```
as_datetime(1618304423122/1000)
```